# ¿Como sumar valores obtenidos del mismo campo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Me gustaría calcular los valores de una campo especifico de mi tabla `item_compras`

```
create_table "item_compras", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "cantidad_bidon"
    t.integer  "total_bidones"
end
```

Estoy utilizando `accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_compras`, en el modelo `Compra`, por lo cual en el formulario de compras puedo ingresar más de un `item_compra`.

Supongamos que ingreso un `item_compra` que tiene `5` en `cantidad_bidon` y otro tiene `4`, lo que como resultado debería guardarse en el campo `total_bidones` dando un total de `9` bidones, pero si solo ingreso un `item_compra`, se debe guardar el item sin realizar ninguna operación. ¿Esto lo puedo hacer con un `after_create`?

**EDICIÓN**

Estoy usando `after_create :total_bidones_compra` en el modelo `ItemCompra`

`def total_bidones_compra
    suma = self.cantidad_bidon + self.cantidad_bidon
    self.total_bidones = suma
    self.save
end`

De esta forma solamente estaría haciendo la suma de solo `2` items, pero si ingreso más de esta cantidad, no sigue sumando.

En el controlador `Compras`, simplemente agrego los atributos del modelo `ItemCompra`

```
def compra_params
  params.require(:compra).permit(..., 
    item_compras_attributes: [:id, :cantidad_bidon, :product_id, :calibre_id, :kg_bidon, :precio_kg, :_destroy ])
end
```

**EDICIÓN N° 2**

Acción del `ComprasController`

```
  def new
    @compra = Compra.new
    5.times { @compra.item_compras.build }
  end


  def create
   @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
   respond_to do |format|
    if @compra.save
      format.html { redirect_to @compra, notice: 'La compra ha sido creada exitosamente.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @compra }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @compra.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No necesitas `after_create` (ni _callback_ alguno), lo puedes hacer en tu controlador al recibir los datos (o en algún otro método en tu modelo): ¿podrías mostrar el código de tu controlador donde recibes los datos del formulario?

Comment: Esto es lo que entiendo. En item_compra 1 tienes cantidad_bidon=5, En item_compra 2 tienes cantidad_bidon=4, entonces deberías tener total_bidones=9 tanto en item_compra 1 como en 2, porque es la suma de cantidad_bidon totales. Si esto es asi ¿por que repetir el total N veces? ¿por que no poner el total en alguna de las tablas padre? Puedes hacerlo en un after_create, pero no especificas cuales serían los criterios para hacer esa sumatoria ¿debes sumar la cantidad de bidones para un mismo item?¿para una misma compra? Mas info por favor

Comment: @Gerry, agregué la información del controlador, simplemente estoy pasando los atributos del modelo ItemCompra para poder realizar el registro de los datos.

Comment: @AlterLagos, al parecer solo es sumatoria básica, utilizo el :after_create porque después de crear el registro mediante el formulario puedo realizar la operatoria con la información que agregue en la edición de la publicación, sin embargo estoy logrando sumar no más de dos cantidades de items.

Comment: ¿Pero es correcto el ejemplo de Alter Lagos? Es decir, ¿todos los items de la compra deben guardarse con la suma de `cantidad_bidones`?

Comment: Pues claro, todos los items de la  compra tienen un `id` y `cantidad_bidon`, se debe calcular el total de esto y guardarse en `total_bidones`

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la acción de tu controlador donde recibes los parámetros y cómo los guardas actualmente?

Comment: Es lo que añadí en la edición.

Comment: Añadiste tu método para filtrar los parámetros (_strong params_) pero faltabla accuón del controlador que crea/guarda los items.

Comment: @Gerry, solo estoy enviando los items desde el formulario de compras y se están guardando en la base de datos, nada más que eso y la operación la estaba realizando en el modelo Compra, con el after_create. Agregaré la acción del controlador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría en el controlador, sumando todos los valores de `:cantidad_bidon` y agregándolos al objeto `@compra` antes de guardarlo.

Podrías hacerlo directamente en tu acción `create` o, mejor aún, genera un método adicional para hacerlo (y pongo como privado):

```
private

def actualiza_total_bidones!
  items = params[:compra][:item_compras_attributes]
  total = items.values.map { |item| item[:cantidad_bidon].to_i }.reduce(:+)

  @compra.item_compras.each { |item| item.total_bidones = total }
end
```

Este método lo que hace es obtener todos los valores de `cantidad_bidon` para cada item recibido y sumarlos para obtener el total; una vez que tienes el total entonces se itera en cada item creado en `@compra` actualizando el atributo `total_bidones` con el total obtenido.

Ahora únicamente llama el método en tu acción `create` después de crear el objeto `@compra` pero antes de salvarlo:

```
def create
  @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
  actualiza_total_bidones!             # <-- Agrégalo aquí

  respond_to do |format|
    // ...
  end
end
```

De esta forma actualizarás con cualquier cantidad de items que reciba tu controlador.

---

Para complementar la respuesta considerando tu comentario

> ... calcular otros valores del mismo modelo, por ejemplo: cantidad_bidon *
>   total_kg.

La lógica sigue siendo la misma, en este caso necesitas calcular `total_kg` (que imagino es el la suma del parámetro `kg_bidon` de cada ítem; en ese caso calcularías `total_kg` de la misma forma que `total_bidones` pero cambiando el parámetro `cantidad_bidon` por `kg_bidon`:

```
total = items.values.map { |item| item[:kg_bidon].to_i }.reduce(:+)
```

Pero en lugar de repetir el método anterior, ahora es buen momento para separarlo en dos métodos, quedando así:

```
# Devuelve la suma del valor del atributo dado en todos los items de la compra
def obtiene_total(atributo)
  items = params[:compra][:item_compras_attributes]
  items.values.map { |item| item[atributo].to_i }.reduce(:+)
end

# Actualiza el atributo `total_bidones` en cada ítem de la compra.
def actualiza_total_bidones!(total_bidones)
  @compra.item_compras.each { |item| item.total_bidones = total_bidones }
end
```

Y ahora podemos agregar un método nuevo para actualizar el nuevo campo (no tengo el nombre así que utilizaré `total_kg_bidones`):

```
# Actualiza el atributo `total_kg_bidones` en cada ítem de la compra.
def actualiza_total_kg!(total_kg)
  @compra.item_compras.each { |item| item.total_kg_bidones = item.cantidad_bidon * total_kg  }
end
```

Finalmente, sólo debes llamar los métodos en la acción `create` del controlador:

```
def create
  @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
  actualiza_total_bidones!(obtiene_total(:cantidad_bidon))
  actualiza_total_kg!(obtiene_total(:kg_bidon))

  respond_to do |format|
    // ...
  end
end
```

Siguiendo esta lógica puedes seguir agregando cálculos, simplemente debes iterar todos los items que hayas recibido en `params` cuando necesites sumatorias (o cualquier operación que involucre todos los items) o bien, haciendo operaciones directas entre los atributos de cada ítem.

Este código funciona, sin embargo sería un buen ejercicio de *refactorización*:

- Cambiar el método `obtiene_total` para poder obtener todos los totales que requieres un una sola vuelta (en lugar de iterar `params` para cada total).
- Mover la lógica de `actualiza_total_bidones` y `actualiza_total_kg` a tu modelo `ItemCompra`.

Comment: El método `actualiza_total_bidones!` podrías dividirlo en dos métodos, para separar la responsabilidad de obtener el total de bidones y actualizar el los bidones en cada ítem.

Comment: Es justamente lo que estaba buscando. ¿Me podrías orientar de alguna forma para realizar otras operaciones con esos valores para multiplicar o dividir?

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Sí, seguro. Aunque necesitaría más información. ¿Qué tanto difiere el cálculo comparado con la suma?

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Por cierto, si la respuesta resuelve el problema original puedes aceptarla (dando click en la paloma).

Comment: es más o menos lo mismo, es para calcular otros valores del mismo modelo, por ejemplo: cantidad_bidon * total_kg.

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Checa la respuesta actualizada, agregué el código para resolver el ejemplo `cantidad_bidon * total_kg`; ese te servirá como guía para cualquier otro cálculo que requieras.

Comment: Quite el signo de admiración en la linea  `actualiza_total_bidones(obtiene_total(:cantidad_bidon))!`, ya que me mostraba el siguiente error: **`syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting keyword_end`**. Ahora exactamente lo que busco es calcular `:cantidad_bidon * :kg_bidon` dando como resultado el `:total_kg`.

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Bien, el signo de admiración es parte del nombre del método (se me escapó ese error); ya corregí la respuesta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59389/discussion-between-mosiah-ricardo-and-gerry).